# C# Do not aggregate using GroupBy if value is NULL using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list where I am merging them if `LineId` is same. This logic works in all scenarios but one. Here, this `LineId` can be `""` or `null` and I do not want to merge it if this is the case.

How can I not merge the list in my query when `LineId` is `""` or `null`?

Code:

```
var groupedLines = lines
    .GroupBy(line => line.LineId)
    .Select(linesGroup => linesGroup.Aggregate((firstLine, nextLine) =>
    {
        // Logic is working as expected

        return firstLine;
    })).ToList();
```

I tried following but it still merges

```
.GroupBy(line => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(line.LineId) )
```

Example 1: (Working as expected)

Input

```
{
  "Lines": [
    {
      "Id": "1",
      "AccountingTotal": 10.2,
      "Description": "Description 1",
      "Price": "10.00",
      "Total": "10.00",
      "LineId": "101" <-- Merge because it is same
    },
    {
      "Id": "2",
      "AccountingTotal": 10,
      "Description": "Description 2",
      "Price": "10.00",
      "Total": "10.00",
      "LineId": "101" <-- Merge because it is same
    }
  ]
}
```

Output

```
{
  "Lines": [
    {
      "Id": "1|2",
      "AccountingTotal": 20.2,
      "Description": "Description 1|Description 1",
      "Price": "20.00",
      "Total": "20.00",
      "LineId": "101"
    }
  ]
}
```

Example-2: (Not working as expected)

Input

```
{
  "Lines": [
    {
      "Id": "1",
      "AccountingTotal": 10.2,
      "Description": "Description 1",
      "Price": "10.00",
      "Total": "10.00",
      "LineId": "" <-- Do not merge if this is "" or null
    },
    {
      "Id": "2",
      "AccountingTotal": 10,
      "Description": "Description 2",
      "Price": "10.00",
      "Total": "10.00",
      "LineId": "" <-- Do not merge if this is "" or null
    }
  ]
}
```

Expected Result

```
{
  "Lines": [
    {
      "Id": "1",
      "AccountingTotal": 10.2,
      "Description": "Description 1",
      "Price": "10.00",
      "Total": "10.00",
      "LineId": ""
    },
    {
      "Id": "2",
      "AccountingTotal": 10,
      "Description": "Description 2",
      "Price": "10.00",
      "Total": "10.00",
      "LineId": "" 
    }
  ]
}
```

Actual Result

```
{
  "Lines": [
    {
      "Id": "1|2",
      "AccountingTotal": 20.4,
      "Description": "Description 1|Description 2",
      "Price": "20.00",
      "Total": "20.00",
      "LineId": ""
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just filter collection **before** grouping to exclude null or empty `LineId`'s by using `Where` method:

```
var groupedLines = lines
     /* here --> */.Where(line => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(line.LineId))
                   .GroupBy(line => line.LineId)
                   .Select(linesGroup => linesGroup.Aggregate((firstLine, nextLine) =>
                   {
                       // Logic is working as expected
                       return firstLine;
                   }))
                   .ToList();
```

Comment: This will return 0 as list since it will eliminate object based on `where` condition.

Comment: Forgot to add `line.LineId` into null/empty check. Thanks for notation, updated answer

Answer (score 0):

You can't put the filter in the GroupBy element.
But you can filter the lines that you don't want to merge in one variable. Then you make the aggregate in another variable and join both variables together before Tolist step.

```
var linesNull = lines.Where(ln => String.IsNullOrEmpty(ln.LineId)); 
var groupedLines = lines.Where(ln => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(ln.LineId))
                        .GroupBy(line => line.LineId)
                        .Select(linesGroup => linesGroup.Aggregate((firstLine, nextLine) =>
    {
        // Logic is working as expected

        return firstLine;
    })).Union(linesNull).ToList();
```